# list package `MoveToFront` not working for me

Tags: list, go

New to Go and building a simple LRU cache in Go to get used to syntax and Go development.

Having an issue with the `MoveToFront` list method, it fails on the following check in the `MoveToFront` body

```
if e.list != l || l.root.next == e
```

I want to move the element (e) to the front of the list when I retrieve it from cache , like this

```
if elem, ok := lc.entries[k]; ok {
    lc.list.MoveToFront(elem) // needs fixing
    return elem
}
return nil
```

The Code can be seen here on line 32 the issue occurs

https://github.com/hajjboy95/golrucache/blob/master/lru_cache/lrucache.go#L32

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems, to me.  First, this isn't how the List data type is meant to be used: `lc.list.PushFront()` will *create* a `List.Element` and return a pointer to it.  That's not fatal, but at the least, it is kind of annoying—the caller has to dig through the returned `List.Element` when using `Get`, instead of just getting the value.

Meanwhile, presumably the failure you see is because you remove elements in `Put` when the LRU-list runs out of space, but you don't remove them from the corresponding map.  Hence a later `Put` of the just-removed key will try to re-use the element in place, even though the element was removed from the list.  To fix this, you'll need to hold both key and value.  (In my simple experiment I did not see any failures here, but the problem became clear enough.)

I restructured the code somewhat and turned it into a [working example on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/peBi8i_mDD1).  I make no promises as to suitability, etc.